# date format in DB not same as output

Tags: php, mysql, date, format, date-format

I'm looking to echo the date from a mysql table on a page, though it is not doing it in the format I would like.
In the table the format is as follows : "06-Feb-2015" which is ideal....

Though when I grab that from the table (this is used in php):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `Expiry` FROM `QA_Data`
```

and:

```
 $row = $sql->fetch();
 echo $row['Expiry'];
```

it echo's it out as "2015-02-06"

I''m sure this can be approached from the php or the mysql side but I would prefer the php answer if possible!

Thanks a million

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$date = "2015-02-06";
echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($date));
```

**Output**

```
06-Feb-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use date and strtotime functions [Date Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

```
$date = $row['Expiry'];
echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yon can convert the date to a string in mySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`Expiry` , '%d-%b-%Y') AS Expiry;
```

and:

```
$row = $sql->fetch();
echo $row['Expiry'];
```

From: [date_format function manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

But if you prefer php side:

```
$row = $sql->fetch();
echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime($row['Expiry']));
```